# How do I set alternate keys for a given command?

Tags: xcode4

Preferences is bound to command+, by default.  Suppose I want to add an additional key binding so that F2 (for example) **also** binds to Preferences?  It must be possible because a few of the standard commands have alternate keystrokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs this is possible, but only with text commands.

"To add a sequence to an existing one, click the Add (+) button and type the new sequence. This only works for text commands; you cannot assign more than one sequence to a menu command."

You can find that in "Xcode 4.2 Developer Lbrary / Tools & Languages / IDEs / Key Bindings Preferences Help / Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts"

Comment: Thanks.  At least I won't go nuts continuing to look.